# constructor and copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class t{
private:
int * arr;

public:
    t() { arr=new int[1]; arr[0]=1;}
    t(int x) {arr=new int[1]; arr[0]=x;}
    t(const t &);
    ~t() {cout<<arr[0]<<"   de"<<endl; delete [] arr;}
    t & operator=(const t & t1){arr[0]=t1.arr[0];return *this;}
    void print(){cout<<arr[0]<<endl;}

};
t::t(const t & t1) {arr=new int[1];arr[0]=t1.arr[0];}

int main(){

   t b=5;
   cout<<"hello"<<endl;
   b.print();
   b=3; 
   b.print();
   return 0;
}
```

Why the result is

```
hello
5
3   de 
3
3   de ?
```

why "t b=5;" will not call the destructor? how "t b=5" works? does it create a temp object (of class t) using constructor "t(int x)" first, then use copy constructor "t(const t &)" to create b?
if it is the case why it does not call the desctructor for the temp object?

Answer (score 2):

> why "t b=5;" will not call the destructor?

When you do this:

```
t b=5;
```

you get [copy initialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm). Semantically, the implicit converting constructor `t(int)` is called, and then the copy constructor `t(const t&)` is called to instantiate `b`. However, the compiler is allowed to [elide the copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), which is what is happening in your case. The object is constructed in place, without need for a copy construction. This is why you do not see a destructor call. But your class still needs a copy constructor for that code to compile: copy elision is optional, and whether some code compiles should not depend on whether the compiler is performing an elision or not.

If you had said

```
t b(5);
```

*then* there would be a direct initialization, with no copy elision, and with only one constructor call. Your class would not require a copy constructor in for this code to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have an assignment operator taking an `int`, `b = 3;` is interpreted as

```
`b.operator=(t(3));`
```

This creates a temporary `t` instance, and destroys it once the assignment returns. That's what prints the first `de` line. Finally, at the end of `main`, `b` goes out of scope, its destructor is called and prints the second line.

Comment: @juanchopanza Why? Which object do you believe is destroyed before "hello"? Note that `t b=5;` is **not** an assignment, it's an initialization. It uses `t(int)` constructor, not `operator=`.

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer. I thought you were talking about the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little trace from your program help you understand what is happing:

```
int main(){
  t b=5;  // as you expected, this call the constructor of your object. 
  cout<<"hello"<<endl;
  b.print();  // as you could see, this call print() and print 5
  b=3;   // this is where the confusion begins. You didn't provide a way 
         // from your object to make an assigment from an integer, but you 
         // provide a way to construct an object from integer. So, your 
         // compiler will construct a temporary object, with 3 as parameter 
         // and use this object to do this assignment. Once this is a 
         // temporary object, it will be destructed at the end of this 
         // operation. That is why you are getting the message: 3   de
  b.print(); // print 3 as expected
  return 0;  // call the destruct from the object that was assigned before
}
```

Comment: OP is asking why `t b=5;` is *not* resulting in a destructor call, so the behaviour is not completely "as you expected". There are annoying subtleties in this very simple line :-)

Comment: I guess, OP is asking why `t b=5` doesn't call a destructor while `b=3` calls it. And the answer is because `t b=5`is a constructor, while `b=3`is an assignment.

Comment: See my answer. `t b=5;` requires a copy constructor, but copy constructions *can* be elided (and are, more often than not). But on a non-eliding implementation, or if you switch off copy elision on your compiler, you *would* see the copy and the destructor call.